# Вызов модального окна ajax запросом

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Пытаюсь вызвать модальное окно с помощью ajax запроса но есть проблема. Окно по нажатию на кнопку вызывается только со 2 раза и после не закрывается и нечего с ним не сделаешь. Вот мой код:
Код основного вью с которого вызывается модалка:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@model IEnumerable<AjaxTest.Models.Book>

<h2>Каталог книг</h2>

<input id="modShow" type="submit" value="Добавить" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mod" />

<div id="result"></div>

<body>
    <div>
        <table id="tab" class="table" table-bordered>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Название</th>
                    <th>Автор</th>
                    <th>Цена</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Author)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Price)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

<h2>Список пользователей</h2>

<body>
    <div>
        <table class="table" table-bordered>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Имя</th>
                    <th>Фамилия</th>
                    <th>Возраст</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Users as List<AjaxTest.Models.User>)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Surname)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Age)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Create",
                data: {
                    "Name": $('#txtName').val(),
                    "Author": $('#txtAuthor').val(),
                    "Price": $('#txtPrice').val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#tab tbody').append(data);
                }
            });
        });

        $('#result').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#result').remove();
        });

        $('#modShow').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/ModalCreate",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Код контроллера:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ModalCreate()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

Код частичного представления с модалкой:

```
<div id="mod" class="modal fade" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Новая книга</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Название</p></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtName" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Автор</p></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtAuthor" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Цена</p></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtPrice" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                <button id="btnAdd" type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?

Добавил кнопку для отображения модалки и изменил ту которая раньше этим занималась, вот их код:

```
<input id="modRender" type="submit" value="Добавить" />
<button style="display: none" id="modShow"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mod"></button>
```

Теперь одна кнопка выводит partial view на страницу а вторая вызывает модальное окно. Ещё само собой изменённый код ajax запроса который всё это вызывает и метод удаляющий объект.

```
$('#result').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#result*').remove();
        });

        $('#modRender').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/ModalCreate",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                    $('#modShow').click();
                }
            });
        });
```

Получается когда срабатывает событие закрытия модального окна, я удаляю всё что находится в div с id result. А потом заного окно не вызывается, что я делаю не так подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Попробовал ещё по другому. Так окошко вызывается с 1 раза, но после закрытия я удаляю этот объект что бы потом заного снова создался но почему то больше не вызывается. Изменеия кода приведу в конце вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятный вызов модалки через $('#modShow').click(); попробуй так

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
    $('#mod').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Nsk я так уже сделал всё работает. Теперь другой есть вопрос. Если хотите помочь вот ссылка. Там уже другая проблема. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/923263/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0